# Bad file descriptor issue in a server application

Tags: c, http, streaming, posix, file-descriptor

Curretly I'm working on a project, where I'm using a litte C application I found to stream a video to a HTML5-GUI.

[I found the source code on this blog](http://systemsdaemon.blogspot.de/2011/03/http-streaming-video-using-program-in-c.html)

For some basic things this code works fine. The only thing I wanted to change is to read in the filesize of the videofile from another file. Therefore I was reading in the file in C:

```
char file_buf[32];
input = fopen("size.dat", "r");
fgets(file_buf, 32, input);
num_chunks = atoi(file_buf);
videosize = (num_chunks-1)*1024;
fclose(input);
printf("videosize: %d",videosize);
```

Now, I get a "bad file descriptor" error, even if I dont alternate anything of the other code. What is the problem here?

Edit: Tested the application more and more, the fault seems to be quite random.... Any ideas?

Edit2: The Error occurs, when the socket should be accepted. The code looks like that:

```
if((socketfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==-1){
        printf("Socket creation failed!\n");
    }
printf("Socket Creation: %s\n",strerror(errno));

bzero(&sockserv,sizeof(sockserv));

sockserv.sin_family = AF_INET;
sockserv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sockserv.sin_port = htons(8080);

if(bind(socketfd,(struct sockaddr *)&sockserv,sizeof(sockserv))<0)
    {
    printf("Error binding the socket\n");
    }
printf("Socket Bind: %s\n",strerror(errno));

if(listen(socketfd,1) == -1){
printf("Listening to Socket failed \n");
}
printf("Socket Listen: %s\n",strerror(errno));

clientfd = accept(socketfd,(struct sockaddr*) &sockclient,&clientsocklen);
if(clientfd  < 0){
    printf("Accepting Socket failed!\n");
}
```

What might be the problem there?

Best regards,
PG

Comment: Check if `input != NULL`

Comment: input is fine. Did some research and looked at the code, atoi() seems to make problems. Tested strtol(), doesn't seem better either...

Comment: The code you linked to, and the code you posted,  doesn't check for *any* errors whatsoever, and its has multiple pntential buffer overflow vulnerabilites. Start fixing the code, and add error checks for all calls that can fail.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have an example, where there might be a buffer overflow issue in this code?
The application fails when it wants to read the incoming data.

Comment: Please note that the [`bzero()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/bzero.html) function has been deprecated since `IEEE Std 1003.1-2001`, and should be replaced with calls to [`memset()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memset.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your problem is due to bound address not being properly reused when you restart your application. Take a look at `SO_REUSEADDR` option. Specifically, you should set it before `bind()`, using `setsockopt()`.